# How do I attach an IC chip to a DIN rail?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, chip-design, din-rail, panel-mounting

I am using a 74AHCT125N to shift up voltage of pwm signal. The problem we are having is how to attach this chip to DIN rail. We were thinking of using a DIN rail mounted PCB. I am looking for solutions, suggestions other than that?

Thank you very much for your help!

74AHCT125N: 
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/SN74AHCT125N/296-4655-5-ND/375798

Comment: This is sort of like asking "How do I attach a picture frame to a bicycle?", because the short answer is "Why would you want to do that? This is not a 'normal' thing to want to do.". But in any event, cyanoacrylate glue ("superglue") will probably work as well as anything else.

Comment: You have decided to mount a circuit involving a specific IC on a DIN rail (presumably attached to a subpanel). You are going to need a PCB for the chip. And you want suggestions **other than** a "DIN rail mounted PCB"? gak. BTW that chip is not a level translator- are you sure you don't want something more like [this](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lv4t125/datasheet) ?

Comment: I am sure that the chip I mentioned is good enough for our project. Normally, we can solder the chip to a PCB and mount that PCB to a DIN rail. I do not know if we may have any other solution (like a thing to just plug the chip in???). Anw, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to buy electronics housings that mount on a DIN rail. Try a search for "DIN rail enclosure". Having got a housing, mount the chip on a PCB, along with other support components, power supply, and so on, and put the PCB inside.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done so far. I got an enclosure, DIN rails and all components organized inside the enclosure. I am looking for an idea other than DIN rail mounted PCB for the "floating" chip. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Linh The point is that you shouldn't have a floating chip—even something as simple as a level shifter should have a bypass capacitor.

Comment: oh no, by "floating" I mean its position is not fixed, not the connection. Sr about my word choice. I can use a breadboard, mount the chip on it along with other components. But I am thinking of a way to mount it onto a DIN rail.

Comment: @Linh A breadboard is not reliable for long-term connections. Just solder up a board and put it in an enclosure. If you don't want to order PCBs, you can use proto board.

Comment: Yes, solder to a proto board or a pcb, then I can attach it to a DIN rail mounted PCB (or proto board) holder and mount them onto a DIN rail. I do understand that solution but I am looking for a different idea (maybe a way that we do not need to solder??? I dont know if there is any better way)

Answer (score 1):

I've used several solutions.  These examples are from a company with initials of "PC", but there are many options from other similar manufacturers as well:

Home -> Products -> Electronics housings -> DIN rail housings

[image: 3 different options of DIN MNT]

- The left option is easy and cheap (and readily available).
- The middle option is new to me.  It looks convenient for emergency
  prototyping.  I do not not how well stocked this is (or price).
- I use the option on the right for all sorts of DIN rail mount uses
  (not just PCB's).

Good luck!

-Chris

Comment: Farnell have that middle option in stock in the UK. About £10 for the case and terminals, another £10 for the proto board. Looked at using one recently, still might.

Comment: @Linh if either answer was useful to you, please mark as "answered" to close this out...